# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\View' not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, namespaces, laravel-artisan

I am new in Laravel. My view is not for the controller why it is .
my view :
`

```
<div class="imgcontainer">

    <img src="img/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">

</div>

<div class="container">

    <label><b>Username</b></label>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label><b>Password</b></label>

    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>

    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me

</div>

<div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">

    <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>

    <span class="signup">New user <a href="signup">Sign Up?</a></span>

</div>

<div>

    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>

</div>
```

`

my controller is:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public $restful = true;

    public function showLogin()
    {
        // show the form
        return View::make('HomeController.login');
    }

    public function doLogin()
    {
        // process the form
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add:

```
use View;
```

after line:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

without it, you are trying to use `View` from current namespace and this is `App\Http\Controllers`

Comment: it was not correct I get this error now   
     * Find the given view in the list of paths. param  string  $name param  array   $paths return string
     throws \InvalidArgumentException
    protected function findInPaths($name, $paths)
    {foreach ((array) $paths as $path) { foreach ($this->getPossibleViewFiles($name) as $file) { if ($this->files->exists($viewPath = $path.'/'.$file)) { return $viewPath;} }} throw new InvalidArgumentException("View [$name] not found.");
    }

Comment: I got the correction that it should be remove controller name from the return statement and it should be only view name. like  return View::make('login');